# What would be the regex for this?

Tags: php, regex

The variable `$description` which contains some text ***may*** also contain a string like so:

```
!some_text_that_may_be_different_each_time!
```

I need to get rid of these, so I tried:

```
$new_description = preg_replace("!.+?!", '', $description);
```

But no luck. What would be a good way to get rid of these strings?

Also removing them may leave extra spaces. For example:

```
Hi world how are ya !asdasdasdasdasd! blue chickens
```

would become

```
Hi world how are ya  blue chickens
```

As you can see now there are 2 spaces between `ya` and `blue`. I would like these to turn to one space as well.

Comment: A couple notes: your regex won't work at all because it's using `!` as the delimiter.  You need another delimiter.  You also don't need the question mark after the plus.

Comment: I think this hould work: `$new_description = preg_replace("/!.+!/i", '', $description);`

Comment: @tandu: The `?` is needed if inputs like `foo !bar! baz !bar2! etc` need to be supported.

Comment: @KennyTM  How do you figure?  That regex would replace `!bar! baz !bar2!` whether the question mark was there or not.

Comment: and for the witespace change the regex to `/\s+/i`

Comment: @tandu: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

Comment: @tandu, a greedy regex (without the ?) would replace "!bar! baz !bar2!" to "", whereas making it ungreedy would make it " baz "

Comment: @tandu,  The ? makes it non-greedy; so it matches the first available !.  In your case `!bar!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a regex like

```
/![^!]+! */
```

note the " *" at the end to eat up any spaces after it.

**Edit**: Additionally, you didn't use the / / delimiters denoting the regex in your example, which is probably why your test didn't work. I opted for [^!]+ (string not containing '!') instead of .+?, which is an ungreedy match, out of habit. I'm not certain if it's faster or not, but in this example it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what you have done differently to the OP

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$new_description = preg_replace("/\s*![^!]+!/", '', $description);
```

If there is a space(s) before the ! you will replace it, and therefore you will just have one space (the last one). 
Notice that what you were doing is use `"!"` as the delimiters of the regex and therefore it wasn't matching.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a simple method.  Just replace everthing in between exclamation points and then replace two spaces with one space.

```
$new_description = preg_replace("!.*?!", '', $description);
$new_description = preg_replace(" +", ' ', $new_description);
```